# How do i override a View attachment glossary fields link or url

Tags: views

Is there a way of overriding an `attachment views` field's url link that is in glossary mode?

I've tried altering the url and link property of the field in the pre-render and post render theme functions, and I can alter their values but it never sticks. I've tried the `.tpl.php` file but then the html tags.

I need to make them links to anchor links show.

Answer (score 0):

So i dont have a definitive yes or no, but if i was to wager a bet i would say... No. There is no way of overriding the glossary mode's url link and make it link to content on the current page. I saw someone else ask this question better than I did back in 2012 and no one answered him, which pushed me to do this in the old way, by building a custom html table and doing the leg work there. So the answer is no need to, just do it in the .tpl.php file.